# How to implement this without triggering an infinite loop with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a situation where I have this component that shows a user list. First time the component loads it gives a list of all users with some data. After this based on some interaction with the component I get an updated list of users with some extra attributes. The thing is that all subsequent responses only bring back the users that have these extra attributes. So what I need is to save an initial state of users that has a list of all users and on any subsequent changes keep updating/adding to this state without having to replace the whole state with the new one because I don't want to lose the list of users.
So far what I had done was that I set the state in Redux on that first render with a condition:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(users === undefined) {
    setUsers(userDataFromApi)
  }
  userList = users || usersFromProp
})
```

The above was working fine as it always saved the users sent the first time in the a prop and always gave priority to it. Now my problem is that I'm want to add attributes to the list of those users in the state but not matter what I do, my component keeps going into an infinite loop and crashing the app. I do know the reason this is happening but not sure how to solve it. Below is what I am trying to achieve that throws me into an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(users === undefined) {
      setUsers(userDataFromApi)
    } else {
      //Users already exist in state
      const mergedUserData = userDataFromApi.map(existingUser => {
        const matchedUser = userDataFromApi.find(user => user.name === existingUser.name);
        if (matchedUser) {
          existingUser.stats = user.stats;
       }
       return existingUser;
       
     })
     setUsers(mergedUserData)
    }
  }, [users, setUsers, userDataFromApi])
```

So far I have tried to wrap the code in else block in a separate function of its own and then called it from within useEffect. I have also tried to extract all that logic into a separate function and wrapped with useCallback but still no luck. Just because of all those dependencies I have to add, it keeps going into an infinite loop. One important thing to mention is that I cannot skip any dependency for useCallback or useEffect as the linter shows warnings for that. I need to keep the logs clean.
Also that setUsers is a dispatch prop. I need to keep that main user list in the Redux store.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction.
Thank you!

Comment: Use the callback syntax for `setUsers` and omit `users` from your dependency array. `setUsers(currentValue => { /* do logic using current value and return new value */ });`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.When I tried the useCallback I passed in userDataFromApi but with that logic I still had to add setUsers and and users as a dependency. Where will be the logic to set the state when it is undefined go, may be I pass userDataFromApi and user both to the function wrapped with useCallback?

Comment: See my answer with example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is based on an interaction could this not be handled by the the event caused by the interaction?

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case "setUsers":
            return {
                users: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const Example = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const users = useSelector(state => state.users)

    useEffect(() => {
        const asyncFunc = async () => {
            const apiUsers = await getUsersFromApi();
            dispatch({ type: "setUsers", payload: apiUsers });
        };

        // Load user data from the api and store in Redux.
        // Only do this on component load.
        asyncFunc();
    }, [dispatch]);


    const onClick = async () => {
        // On interaction (this case a click) get updated users.
        const userDataToMerge = await getUpdatedUserData();

        // merge users and assign to the store.
        if (!users) {
            dispatch({ type: "setUsers", payload: userDataToMerge  });
            return;
        }
        
        const mergedUserData = users.map(existingUser => {
            const matchedUser = action.payload.find(user => user.name === existingUser.name);

            if (matchedUser) {
                existingUser.stats = user.stats;
            }

            return existingUser;
        });

        dispatch({ type: "setUsers", payload: mergedUserData  });
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={onClick}>
            This is a placeholder
        </div>
    );
}
```

**OLD ANSWER (useState)**

`setUsers` can also take a callback function which is provided the current state value as it's first parameter: `setUsers(currentValue => newValue);`

You should be able to use this to avoid putting users in the dependency array of your useEffect.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUsers(currentUsers => {
        if(currentUsers === undefined) {
            return userDataFromApi;
        } else {
            //Users already exist in state
            const mergedUserData = currentUsers.map(existingUser => {
                const matchedUser = userDataFromApi.find(user => user.name === existingUser.name);

                if (matchedUser) {
                    existingUser.stats = user.stats;
                }

                return existingUser;
            });

            return mergedUserData;
        }
    });
}, [setUsers, userDataFromApi]);
```

Comment: I'll let you know if this works, I'm getting some typescript errors with that setUsers not accepting a function, only accepts an array. So guess I'll have to change it so it accepts a function to return the array, I believe

Comment: Does `setUsers` come from a `useState` hook?

Comment: its a dispatch to store users in Redux store. 
public setUsers(users?: users[]): void { this.draftState = {...this.draftstate, users}
}

Comment: you think if there is a way to get this to work without having to change the parameter type to a callback in the reducer, guess the above will not work ofcourse as the parameter needs to be an array and not a function. I have to keep that main user list in the redux so it can be accessed easily from a few other places in the app.

Comment: Yeah the above will not work with your reducer function, I assumed you were using `useState`, looking at the question, I can clearly see you mention setting the state in Redux. Give me 2 secs

Comment: I'm wondering if all this logic has to move to the reducer

Comment: Moved all that logic into the reducer and still dealing with the same issue.

Comment: Do you have a repo with more of your code visible?

Comment: Sorry I don't but good thing is I didn't have to save the updated state in the store, only saving the first time was enough. So now I am trying to do it like you suggested but I'm stuck at this typescript error. .....not assignable to type SetStateAction<users>It wont let me provide the callback to the setUsers. I have defined it as: const [users, setUsers] = userState<User[]>([]); So it expects an array and not a function. I could change this type but that seems really weird for it to accept either an array or callback that returns an array.

Comment: Playing around with the old example you gave at this sandbox. I'm seeing a really weird behavior, hopefully im not doing something really stupid here :-) https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-sanderson-l2h33?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When you were mapping out the changes you need to return a complete user object from the `map` function, such as: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-cdn-pg7rf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: aha, I knew I was doing something stupid. You know this is something knew for me and helped me solve the issue I'm going to accept your answer

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but do you have any knowledge of testing with jest. I made a separate post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433074/how-can-i-test-all-this-logic-inside-setstate-callback-parameter
I'm struggling to test all that logic inside the setState callback. Thank you!

Comment: Don't know if this has changed and I'm behind the times but I think testing of function components is essentially rendering the component / firing events using your testing library then checking against the rendered DOM. React has some information on it at https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html and Log Rocket did a reasonable write up at: https://blog.logrocket.com/a-quick-guide-to-testing-react-hooks-fa584c415407/

Comment: Yeah I spent all day reading and trying to mock setState or somehow refactor this code so I can test. No worries. I'll keep researching. Thank you.